# K6 Load testing using "batch" not sending the correct request headers

Tags: load-testing, k6

K6 newbie here, currently working on a load test scenario for an API we have.

```
This is a request I am using to hit an API endpoint.

const request1 = {
            method: "POST",
            url: endpointUrl,
            body: requestBody,
            params: {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "custom-header-1": 'value1',
                    "custom-header-2": 'value2', 
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            }
        };

const responses = http.batch([request1])
```

If I execute this request using `http.post`, everything works as expected.

But using `http.batch`, I always get back a `415 Media type unsupported` back from the server. When checking the request sent to my API using `Wireshark`, I can see that the `content-type` being sent is of type `x-www-form-urlencoded`, and not `application/json` as defined in my request. The two custom header values I’m sending are also not visible.

[image]

Based on their example page [K6 batch](https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-http/batch/), I have also tried by defining the request in-line, but the result is the same.

What is missing from my script that my custom `content-type` isn’t getting picked up by the batch function? As you can see, there is a `Requestheaders` header that’s an object, but those values should actually be applied on request level.

Thank you.

By providing the `content-type` as part of the `params.headers` object, I expect this value to get passed on to the request.

Comment: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type indicates the server refuses an unsupported payload format. Could the issue be the format of the requestBody?

You can try using https://k6-http.grafana.fun/ if you want to test k6 APIs. For instance: https://gist.github.com/ppcano/c021ead747de82f44392b638b6cf807b

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the server is sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, therefore the 415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requestBody` I was sending was a `Json` object, like the one on their example page.
The solution is to call the function with `Json.stringify(requestBody)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put `requestBody` into a JSON.stringify() function:

```
body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
```

You need to convert the JSONObject to a string because you're including the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header (or 'Accept' in your case)